# Settings Activity has no XML?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-activity

I have been programming Android for a while now, but this is the first time I ever used the Settings Activity. However, when I create the Settings Activity it doesn't create an XML. Atleast, I can't find it. How do I edit the settings Activity GUI?

Thanks

Comment: You don't create a layout for `PreferenceActivity`. Instead, you set the preferences content in `/xml` folder. Refer to [the official doc about Settings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

Comment: Oooh okay, sometimes I am a moron. Thanks!